# ZF2- Helper doesn't work in application directory

Tags: zend-framework2, view-helpers

I'm trying to add helper to my project, but I get fatal error.
Here is my view helper:

```
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class TestHelper extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return 'Helper works!';
    }
}
```

My global.php

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'test_helper' => 'Application\View\Helper\TestHelper'
    ),
),
```

layout.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->test_helper(); ?>
```

I get fatal error: **Fatal error: Class 'Application\View\Helper\TestHelper' not found in... library\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager.php on line 170**

But if I put directory view/helper/TestHelper.php to other module everything seems to work fine.
Is it not possible to run helpers from Application directory?

Also I have a question about Zend helpers.
I have a part of page which is displayed depending if user is logged or not. It is shown for almost all modules. Is it good idea to keep these helpers in Application module?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe too obiovus: using ClassmapAutoloader and forgot to add it?

Comment: Can you add the path for your helper file? I had a similar issue, but I have now updated the ZF2.2 docs

Comment: I have the same issue, and the solution doesn't work for me. It should be fairly straight-forward, I have controller_plugins that work, the view helpers should be the same. Any other solutions on this?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and it turned out to be simple:

The file 'YourNewViewHelper' should be in folder

```
module\moduleName\src\nameSpace\View\Helper
```

and not in

```
module\moduleName\View\Helper
```